# Possessive have vs had

Tags: word-usage, difference

which sentence is correct?

> you already have one.

or

> you already had one.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences are valid.

Tunny is correct that context is key here. To expand on this:

> You already have one.

would commonly be used where *you already **possess** one*.

> You already had one.

would be used to say *you already **consumed** one*.

### Example:

You would say

> you already have a cookie

to a child who is holding a cookie and asking for another.

But you would say

> you already had a cookie

to a child who already ate a cookie and is asking for another.

Comment: Both versions could refer to possession: "I want a green hat." / "You already had one -- I gave it to you for your birthday two years ago -- and you never wore it, so you ended up throwing it away last year. Remember?"

Comment: @Scott You are correct. I meant to use consumed to mean *used up* or *expended*.

Comment: “I came here for an argument!” No, seriously, I’m not disagreeing with your suggestion that “You already had one.” _could_ refer to a situation where the “one” had been used up or expended; I’m just saying that it can _also_ refer to possession. Modify my example to “… you ended up _giving_ it away last year,” and it’s clear that the hat doesn’t need to be used up or expended (although it probably is _gone_ in some sense).

Comment: @Scott Yeah, I agree that the hat is not *exactly* expended in this case, but as far as *you* is concerned, the hat is a bygone resource. Perhaps it would be more useful for my answer to simply explain that have/had are for present/past tense.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are possible. Only context can tell which is appropriate.